# jinja2 TemplateResponse.template.render() doesn't inject context into template

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using FastAPI with Jinja2.

I have a function that sends out an email. The content of the email is inside a HTML that needs to be rendered.

```
    async def send_confirmation_email(
        self, email: str, confirm_url: str, request: Request
    ):
        html = templates.TemplateResponse(
            "email_template.html",
            {
                "request": request,
                "header": "Thanks for joining",
                "url": confirm_url,
                "link_title": "ACTIVATE YOUR ACCOUNT",
            },
        )
        await self.send_email(
            html.template.render(),
            "Confirm Your Email",
            setting.EMAIL_SUPPORT,
            email,
        )
```

`html.template.render()` is only rendering the content of HTML without filling in the context into the placeholders. e.g. `"header": "Thanks for joining"` remains empty.

snippet from HTML:

```
<td align="center" width="120" colspan="3" valign="top"><h2>{{ header }}</h2></td>
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateResponse` return a `starlette.responses.Response`, not a renderer template .

For that, you need to use

```py
templates.get_template("email_template.html").render({
    "request": request,
    "header": "Thanks for joining",
    "url": confirm_url,
    "link_title": "ACTIVATE YOUR ACCOUNT",
})
```

(ref: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/templating.py#L72)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `html.template.render()` you can use `html.body` which contains an already rendered template.